# ClassNotFoundException after package renaming

Tags: android

hy!

Exception:

```
10-05 15:36:36.609: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(237): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.korn.gpv.Main in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader@44e836b8
```

after changing the package name.

Please help

new package: com.android.korn.gpv

Comment: did you changed it on the manifest file ?? like this : <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.android.korn.gpv" >

Answer (score 2, accepted):

did you changed it on the manifest file ?? like this :

`<manifest xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.android.korn.gpv" >`

Answer (score 2):

If changing the package name in `<manifest>` tag does not work, try changing or adding the name of the activity (Main) to the manifest file as follows.

```
<activity android:name="com.android.korn.gpv.Main" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

If that doesn't work either, make sure that any other files in your project does not refer to `com.korn.gpv.Main` instead of `com.android.korn.gpv.Main`.

Answer (score 0):

When you changed package name also check within the  `<manifest>` tag, that the package will be same as your new package name.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
      package="com.android.korn.gpv" >
```